# Smart gate - where to start?

Tags: smart-home, raspberry-pi, arduino

I have this idea of writing an app/something to make the gate, that we have in front of our house, smart. But I just don't know where to start. 
I assume that the gate uses IR because we have remotes for it, but I'm not sure. The gate also has a codepad and I want everything to work simultaneously. Meaning that when I'm done with my project the remotes and code still work.

So, can anyone help me to get started with this project?

- Would it be logical for the gate to use IR? What would it use otherwise?
- Should I try to read and emit the same signal using a Pi/Arduino?

Comment: Does the gate controller have a button (for inside the house?) that just opens the gate? if so then you can just attach a network controlled relay to the line for the button.

Comment: @hardillb it does. So I do that and I can reach the relay through the wifi network? Do you have a product example? Would the regular button still work if I set it up correctly?

Comment: put the remote conttrol inside you pocket .... does it still operate the gate? .... if it does, then it is an RF remote   .............. how is the codepad connected?

Comment: Okay thanks! It's connected on a pillar next to the gate, exact wiring etc I don't know because I haven't opened it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments...

Assuming the controller has a button that will trigger the gate to open then you just need to find a way to "press" that button.

The simplest way is probably to attach a relay across the 2 wires to the button. The relay can be triggered by something like a esp8266 or the GPIO pins on a raspberry pi.

The question is then if it's a momentary press or if it needs to be held while the gate opens.

If it's momentary then the relay just needs activating for a second, if it's press and hold then you will need to activate the relay for the length of time it takes for the gate to open.

That is a very simple approach and doesn't cover things like feedback on if the gate is open/closed.

Comment: Right. Sounds good! It's a momentary press, so I just need to activate it for second or so that it will register. How would I get feedback?

Comment: No idea, it will depend on if the existing system has any indicator you can tap, or if you have to implement it yourself with limit switches or some other sensor

Comment: That's going to be me implementing it myself.. Thanks!